# Fill cells based on other table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate certain functions in an Excel file.

Here is my issue:

[image: simplified example]

Table 1 contains a string is Column "Info", followed by two empty cells. For each of the rows in Table 1, I want to check if a value of Table 2, Column "Fruit" exists in column "Info" of Table 1. If so, I would like to fill in the "Color" and "Price" of Table 2 in the empty cells in Table 1.

For example, the second row contains the word "bananas", which means "Color" "Yellow" and "Price" "15" should be filled in the same columns in Table 1, row 2.

Somehow this issue seems so simple to me, but when I start to think of how to implement this, I get stuck. So unfortunately, I don't have any code available to fix. I just hope this issue isn't too vague.

I've also tried solving this issue using formulas, using MATCH and INDEX, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Just a small hint  -> why don't you try to do it a bit simpler and then make it more complicated? E.g. for `apples` instead of `This is some line about apples`. There you can use some Index(Match;Match) easily.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree to your point. But this example was just a simplified version of a more complicated sheet. The original sheet contains a lot more rows and the value in the "info" column is a lot more complicated. So substituting these values is not really an option.

EDIT: by the way, substituting these values using VBA, would require a similar script. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will return the row in the ListObject (Table) where the first matching word is found.

```
Public Function MatchFruit(ByVal sInfo As String, ByRef rFruit As Range) As Long

    Dim vaSplit As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sWhat As String

    vaSplit = Split(sInfo, Space(1))

    For i = LBound(vaSplit) To UBound(vaSplit)
        'strip out non-alpha characters
        sWhat = vbNullString
        For j = 1 To Len(vaSplit(i))
            If Asc(Mid(LCase(vaSplit(i)), j, 1)) >= 97 And Asc(Mid(LCase(vaSplit(i)), j, 1)) <= 122 Then
                sWhat = sWhat & Mid(vaSplit(i), j, 1)
            End If
        Next j

        'find the word in the range
        Set rFound = Nothing
        Set rFound = rFruit.Find(sWhat, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then 'if it's found
            'return the row in the ListObject
            MatchFruit = rFound.Row - rFruit.ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Row
            'stop looking
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Assuming your first table is called tblData and your second table tblFruit, you would get the color using

```
=INDEX(tblFruit[Color],MatchFruit([@Info],tblFruit[Fruit]))
```

and the price similarly

```
=INDEX(tblFruit[Price],MatchFruit([@Info],tblFruit[Fruit]))
```

**Long Explanation**

The `vaSplit` assignment line uses the `Split` function to convert a string into an array based on a delimiter. Since your sample data was sentences, the normal delimiter is a space to split it into words. A string like

```
This is some line about apples.
```

is converted to an array

```
vaSplit(1)  This
vaSplit(2)  is    
vaSplit(3)  some
vaSplit(4)  line
vaSplit(5)  about
vaSplit(6)  apples.
```

Next, the `For` loop goes through every element in the array to see if it can find it in the other list. The functions `LBound` and `Ubound` (lower bound and upper bound) are used because we can't be sure how many elements the array will have.

The first operation inside the loop is to get rid of any extraneous characters. For that, we create the variable `sWhat` and set it to nothing. Then we loop through all the characters in the element to see if any are outside of the range `a...z`. Basically, anything that's a letter gets appended to `sWhat` and anything that's not (a number, a space, a period) doesn't. In the end `sWhat` is the same as the current element with all non-alpha characters stripped out. In this example, we'd never match `apples.` because of the period, so it's stripped away.

Once we have a good `sWhat`, we now use the `Find` method to see if that word exists in the `rFruit` range. If it does, then `rFound` will not be `Nothing` and we move ahead.

Note that if it doesn't find the word in the range, then `rFound` will be `Nothing` and the function will return zero.

If the word is found, the function returns the row it was found on less the row where the `ListObject` starts. That way the function returns what row it is withing the data of the `ListObject` not on the worksheet. This is useful when incorporating into an `INDEX` formula. To make a formula return something, you assign that something to the formula's name.

Finally, the `Exit For` line simply stops looking through the array once a match was found. If you have more than one match in your data, it will only return the first one.

**Troubleshooting**

The most likely error that you'll find is that the function will return zero when you expect it to return a row number. That most likely means it did not find any words in the list.

If you're certain that both lists contain a matching word, here's how you troubleshoot it: After the `Set rFound =` line put a `Debug.Print` statement.

```
        Set rFound = rFruit.Find(sWhat, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
        Debug.Print "." & sWhat & "."
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then 'if it's found
```

That will print `sWhat` to the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G in the VBE to see the Immediate Window). The periods around the word are so you can see any non-printable characters (like spaces). If you try to match `.pears .` with `pears` it won't match because the first one has a space at the end - and you can see that because we stuck periods before and after.

If spaces are going to be a problem, you can use the `Trim$()` function on `sWhat` to get rid of them first.

With that `Debug.Print` statement, you might see results like

```
.paers.
```

in which case would recognize that you have a typo.

Comment: Thanks Dick. This definitely worked. Although I'm not sure yet how and why it's working. But I'll sink my teeth in it and try to figure it out.If I'm correct, this way I still need to enter the formulas manually into the empty cells, which will certainly work for me when updating the file. But is it possible to automate this even further?

Comment: Sorry for being a n00b. Although it is working fine for my example tables, I don't really understand what the function is doing and when trying to adapt the function to my actual sheet, it doesn't work. Could you possibly talk me through the function a bit?

Comment: OK. I'm getting a bit further. I figured why the function was failing. `vaSplit = Split(sInfo, Space(1))` was splitting up the string at each _space_. In my sheet, the string should actually be split by "/", so after changing to `vaSplit = Split(sInfo, "/")` the INDEX formula worked. But now it's returning "0", even though the string should have a match. Continuing investigation.

Comment: @DavedeGroot I added some more details to help you figure out what's happening. If you're getting a zero, it's likely not finding what it needs to find in the table. My thought was that you were using a `Table` and that the formulas would propagate down as you added records and that would be fairly automatic. If you want something different, edit your question with how the code would be triggered. You can definitely use code the fills in two cells to the right and avoid formulas.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After a day of going through your answer, I was getting to understanding it more and more. But your update definitely helped a lot. I'll practice some more to get it to work on my own sheet, which should be possible as it is working for the example. Just need to put in some more time.

Comment: By the way, I figured out that your solution was not exactly what I was looking for, but it is definitely worth a lot in improving my knowledge and experience. And I really appreciate you taking the time for your extensive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To Dick and other people who may be interested. Like I mentioned in my last comment on the answer provided by @Dick-Kusleika, his answer didn't fully cover my initial question. Even though it gave me great insight and it did the job of filling the empty cells with the appropriate data, I was really looking for something that would do it automatically, without me having to copy-paste any formulas. So I spent some more time trying to figure it out, getting info from the internet and sparring with a colleague who shares my interest in this. And eventually I managed to get it working! (hurray!!)

Below is my solution. As I'm still a beginner, I probably did a few things that could have been done better or cleaner. So I'm really interested in your opinion about this and would love to hear any remarks or tips.

```
Sub check_fruit()

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lo_Data As Excel.ListObject
Dim lo_Fruit As Excel.ListObject
Dim lr_Data As Excel.ListRow
Dim lr_Fruit As Excel.ListRow
Dim d_Info As Variant
Dim f_Fruit As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exercise")
Set lo_Data = ws.ListObjects("tblData")
Set lo_Fruit = ws.ListObjects("tblFruit")

For Each lr_Data In lo_Data.ListRows

    'check if field "Color" is empty in tblData'
    If IsEmpty(Intersect(lr_Data.Range, lo_Data.ListColumns("Color").Range).Value) Then
        d_Info = Intersect(lr_Data.Range, lo_Data.ListColumns("Info").Range).Value

        For Each lr_Fruit In lo_Fruit.ListRows
            f_Fruit = Intersect(lr_Fruit.Range, lo_Fruit.ListColumns("Fruit").Range).Value

            'check for each row in tblFruit if value for field "Fruit" exists in field "Info" of tblData'
            If InStr(1, d_Info, f_Fruit, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                Intersect(lr_Data.Range, lo_Data.ListColumns("Color").Range).Value = Intersect(lr_Fruit.Range, lo_Fruit.ListColumns("Color").Range).Value
                Intersect(lr_Data.Range, lo_Data.ListColumns("Price").Range).Value = Intersect(lr_Fruit.Range, lo_Fruit.ListColumns("Price").Range).Value
            End If

        Next lr_Fruit

    End If

Next lr_Data

End Sub
```